# clang-tooling: replacing out parameter with a return value

Tags: c++, clang, clang-tidy

I'm writing a clang tool that would roughly do the following:

Before:

```
encode(in, out);
```

After:

```
out = encode(in);
```

The problem is I would like to remove the unnecessary temporary variables too.

At the very least I'd like:

```
std::string test(std::string_view in) {
  std::string res;
  encode(in, res);
  return res;
}
```

To be replaced with:

```
std::string test(std::string_view in) {
  return encode(in);
}
```

All ideas I have about how to do this are fairly involved, I was wondering if someone has a reasonable answer.

Comment: Would  `auto res = encode(in); return res;` satisfy you?  There are some advantages to this, when debugging.

Comment: I'd prefer to completly remove the temp. But if you know a good way to do your way - I am listening, there might be some way to advance it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use clang tidy, I was just making what I thought might be a helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*NOTE: refactoring I got is fairly at most good-enough for my needs and is likely to break under some non obvious conditions. I intend to code-review the results*.

No smart way was discovered, posting what I got.
Unfortunately my whole code is closed sourced, so I can't post entire solution.

The main thing I didn't know about the solution is that you can run a matcher on a subtree.

Here is a function that returns all of the usages for a given declaration.

```cpp
std::vector<const clang::DeclRefExpr*> findDeclRefs(
    const clang::CompoundStmt* parent,
    const clang::Decl* decl,
    clang::ASTContext& context) {
  using namespace clang::ast_matchers;
  auto matches = match(
      findAll(declRefExpr(hasDeclaration(equalsNode(decl))).bind("usage")),
      *parent,
      context);

  std::vector<const clang::DeclRefExpr*> res;
  for (const auto& match : matches) {
    res.push_back(match.getNodeAs<clang::DeclRefExpr>("usage"));
  }

  return res;
}
```

Here is a function that returns last usage of the out parameter if it's appropriate to replace it (for my case). This is where most of your modifications are likely to be.

```
const clang::DeclRefExpr* canOutParameterBeInlined(
    const clang::CompoundStmt* scope,
    const clang::Expr* param,
    clang::ASTContext& context) {
  using namespace clang::ast_matchers;
  auto* paramVar = llvm::dyn_cast_or_null<clang::DeclRefExpr>(param);

  // Out parameter is not just reference but some complicated expression.
  if (paramVar == nullptr) {
    return nullptr;
  }

  auto* decl = paramVar->getDecl();

  // Out param was declared outside of the scope
  if (match(compoundStmt(hasDescendant(equalsNode(decl))), *scope, context)
          .empty()) {
    return nullptr;
  }

  auto usages = findDeclRefs(scope, decl, context);


  // In order to replace, we should have exactly 2 usages:
  // in the call and in the result.
  if (usages.size() != 2U) {
    return nullptr;
  }

  // shouldn't happen: one usage gotta be the call
  if (usages[0] != paramVar && usages[1] != paramVar) {
    return nullptr;
  }

  // One usage gotta be not the call
  if (usages[0] != paramVar) {
    return usages[0];
  }

  if (usages[1] != paramVar) {
    return usages[1];
  }

  return nullptr;
}
```

PS: I also struggled to remove semicolons.
The function I was looking for is:
`clang::Lexer::findLocationAfterToken(end, clang::tok::semi, ...)`